# List files with certain extensions with ls and grep

Tags: bash, shell, macos, grep

I just want to get the files from the current dir and only output .mp4 .mp3 .exe files nothing else.
So I thought I could just do this:

```
ls | grep \.mp4$ | grep \.mp3$ | grep \.exe$
```

But no, as the first grep will output just mp4's therefor the other 2 grep's won't be used.

Any ideas? PS, Running this script on Slow Leopard.

Comment: This really is the wrong approach -- instead of using grep, use `shopt -s nullglob` and then just refer to `*.exe *.mp3 *.mp4`. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: I can't figure out whether or not "Slow Leopard" was a typo...

Comment: @Wowfunhappy hahaha, definitely was a typo, I recall thinking Snow Leopard was quite fast.

Answer (score 434, accepted):

Why not:

```
ls *.{mp3,exe,mp4}
```

I'm not sure where I learned it - but I've been using this.

Comment: This isn't working for me because the extension I am using is for a directory, so the ls is listing the contents of the directory.

Comment: @RichardVenable add the -d switch to prevent that directories are recursed.

Comment: I like this solution but it seems to fail if you are missing any one of the filetypes. For example, you have mp3 but no .exe (Mac OSX, zsh)

Comment: I redirected stderr to /dev/null to avoid `ls: *.exe: No such file or directory` eg: `ls *.{zip,tar.gz,tar} 2>/dev/null`

Comment: When I run ls foo*.{tar.gz,zip} directly in a shell it works, but when put this inside a shell script latest=$(ls -I '*.done' -tr ${pkgprefix}*.{tar.gz,zip} | tail -1)  I got an error message: ls: cannot access 'bamtools*.{tar.gz,zip}': No such file or directory, any smarter guy can refined the answer.

Answer (score 59):

`egrep` -- extended grep -- will help here

```
ls | egrep '\.mp4$|\.mp3$|\.exe$'
```

should do the job.

Comment: Thats it!
Thanks

Just realized I should have it case insensitive, so I'm using:
ls | egrep -i '\.mp4$|\.mp3$|\.exe$
Incase anyone else needs help with that one day.

Im always surprised by the speed I get my answer on here.

Comment: I can't see how this would work. ls without any options produces output in columns. Anchoring to the end of the line will not match properly.

Comment: @camh: `ls` to a terminal (or with `-C` option) produces multi-column output. `ls` to a pipe (or with `-1`) has single column output. (Compare output of `ls` with `ls | cat`).

Comment: There's a missing apostrophe at the end. Other than that it seems to work.

Answer (score 48):

Use regular expressions with `find`:

```
find . -iregex '.*\.\(mp3\|mp4\|exe\)' -printf '%f\n'
```

If you're piping the filenames:

```
find . -iregex '.*\.\(mp3\|mp4\|exe\)' -printf '%f\0' | xargs -0 dosomething
```

This protects filenames that contain spaces or newlines.

OS X `find` only supports alternation when the `-E` (enhanced) option is used.

```
find -E . -regex '.*\.(mp3|mp4|exe)'
```

Comment: On Mac OS X: `find . -iregex '.*\(mp3\|mp4\|exe\)'`

Comment: andi, that didn't work for me on mac os.  But this did:
find -E . -regex '.*(mp3|mp4|exe)'

Comment: This solution will load files like: `mysupermp3.jpg` consider adding the `$` at the end of the regex and the `\\.` before the extensions

Comment: @Panthro: actually, it won't. Find appears to use implied anchors. The dot is a good idea (only one backslash is needed).

Answer (score 20):

the easiest way is to just use ls

```
ls *.mp4 *.mp3 *.exe
```

Comment: Thanks, but I already tried that and I didn't like the errors you get when there is no file.
Thou I could of fixed that by doing:
ls *.mp4 *.mp3 *.exe 2> /dev/null
Only thought of that now thou :P

Comment: I am surprised that `ls` doesn't have some sort of silent option.

Comment: In bash, you can do "set -o nullglob", and you wont get the errors.

Comment: My mistake - that should be "shopt -s nullglob" not the set -o command

Comment: Or just use "echo": echo *.mp4 *.mp3 *.exe

Comment: This worked for me on my MacOS14 `zshell`

Answer (score 14):

No need for grep. Shell wildcards will do the trick.

```
ls *.mp4 *.mp3 *.exe
```

If you have run

```
shopt -s nullglob
```

then unmatched globs will be removed altogether and not be left on the command line unexpanded.

If you want case-insensitive globbing (so *.mp3 will match foo.MP3):

```
shopt -s nocaseglob
```

Comment: Same comment as I gave to Good Time Tribe.

Comment: I am trying to use this with the `-R` option to list matching files in subdirectories but the option doesn't seem to have any effect and I still only get the current directory's results.

Answer (score 11):

Just in case: why don't you use `find`?

```
find -iname '*.mp3' -o -iname '*.exe' -o -iname '*.mp4'
```

Comment: I found this worked instead - `find . -name '*.mkv' -o -name '*.flv'` (adding as many -o clauses as required). I needed the `.` to indicate the directory and the flag `-name` not `-iname` - I'm on macOS 10.13.

Answer (score 7):

**For OSX users**:

If you use `ls *.{mp3,exe,mp4}`, *it will throw an error* if one of those extensions has no results.

Using `ls *.(mp3|exe|mp4)` will return all files matching those extensions, *even if one of the extensions had 0 results*.

Comment: I got a syntax error using your example???
'bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('

Comment: I guess you mean `ls *.@(mp3|exe|mp4)`. You need `shopt -s extglob` for this to work. By the way, `ls` is useless too, you could just do `printf '%s\n' *.@(mp3|exe|mp4)`.

Comment: I get the syntax unexpected token message on macOS 10.13

Comment: what if my folder has `.h` & `.hpp` files & I only want to list `.h`

Answer (score 5):

In case you are still looking for an alternate solution:

```
ls | grep -i -e '\\.tcl$' -e '\\.exe$' -e '\\.mp4$'
```

Feel free to add more -e flags if needed.

Answer (score 4):

```
ls | grep "\.mp4$
\.mp3$
\.exe$"
```

Comment: Thanks, but a bit inconvenient using up several lines.

Comment: This + `mdfind` yields the best / fastest searches EVER!  `mdfind -name  querystring |  grep "\.h$"`  finds all headers with quesrystring in the file title.  pronto.

Answer (score 0):

`ls -R | findstr ".mp3"`

`ls -R` => lists subdirectories recursively

Answer (score 0):

it is easy try to use this command :

```
ls | grep \.txt$ && ls | grep \.exe
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is one example that worked for me.

```
find <mainfolder path> -name '*myfiles.java' | xargs -n 1 basename
```