# find only files with extension using ls

Tags: linux, bash, ls

I need to find only files in directory which have a extension using ls (can't use find).

I tried ls *.*, but if dir doesn't contain any file with extension it returns "No such file or directory".

I dont want that error and want ls to return to cmd prompt if there are files with extension.

I have trying to use grep with ls to achieve the same.

ls|grep "*.*" - doesn't work
but ls | grep "\." works.

I have no idea why grep *.* doesn't work. Any help is appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: How about `ls|grep '\.'`

Comment: Yes, as mentioned above it works. Can you explain why it does and why \*.\* doesn't?

Comment: `ls *.{mp3,exe,mp4}`

This question should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1447625/list-files-with-certain-extensions-with-ls-and-grep

Comment: grep uses a regular expression, not a shell pattern

Comment: ls is not the tool for the job.  You need to use `find`.  Whatever the constraint against `find` is, please let us know and we'll help you work around it.

Comment: @VaughnCato Except when the "regular expression" is also a glob pattern that is not quoted to protect it from expansion before `grep` even sees it... `grep *.*` is all sorts of fun waiting to happen...

Answer (score 2):

I think the correct solution is this:

```
( shopt -s nullglob ; echo *.* )
```

It's a bit verbose, but it will always work no matter what kind of funky filenames you have. (The problem with piping `ls` to `grep` is that typical systems allow really bizarre characters in filenames, including, for example, newlines.)

The `shopt -s nullglob` part enables ("**s**ets") the `nullglob` **sh**ell **opt**option, which tells Bash that if no files have names matching `*.*`, then the `*.*` should be removed (i.e., should expand into nothing) rather than being left alone.

The parentheses `(...)` are to set up a subshell, so the `nullglob` option is only enabled for this small part of the script.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
ls -1 | grep "\."
```

list only files with extensión and nothing (empty list) if there is no file: like you need.

With Linux grep, you can add -v to get a list files with no extension.

Answer (score 1):

It's important to understand the difference between a shell pattern and a regular expression.  Shell patterns are a bit simpler, but less flexible.  grep matches using a regular expression.  A shell pattern like

```
*.*
```

would be done with a regular expression as

```
.*\..*
```

but the regular expressions in grep are not anchored, which means it searches for a match anywhere on the line, making the two `.*` parts unnecessary.