# Linux Terminal: how to view files with extension using ls command?

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, command

How can I use the `ls` command to print all of those files with a .doc extension *inside* the "tmp" directory? (No find neither grep). Perhaps with `-X` ? How would it be if we used `-X`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're adamant on not using grep or find, as outlined here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1447974/1666167

You can do something like this:

```
ls *.{mp3,exe,mp4}
```

What this looks like for .doc files in the tmp directory is this:

```
ls /tmp/*.doc
```

Comment: error jumps up, need to indicate to search inside tmp directory

Comment: Is that the precise error? I've just tried it myself to double check and it seems okay.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like: `ls *.doc` in the directory.

Comment: " cannot acces */.doc: No such file or directory" i need to add that it should search on the tmp directory

Answer (score 1):

Try this one, should work:

```
 ls *.doc
```