# Make list of objects in global environment matching certain string pattern

Tags: r, regex, list

I have 10 data frames in the global environment- 5 with a name pattern and other 5 with another naming pattern. I want to put the dataframes with same naming pattern into a list each (two lists - one for each pattern) so ultimately I can run checks on each of them using `lapply` like this :

```
 lapply(listofdataframes, function(x) range(x[ , "date"]))`
```

The naming patterns are thus - `Pattern 1` : `q32013local`, `q42013local`, `q12014local`, etc.

`Pattern 2` : `q32013national`, `q42013national` etc.

I have used this in the past:

```
 Filter(function(x) is(x, "data.frame"), mget(ls()))`
```

but it obviously makes a list of all data frames in global environment.

I was looking for how to use `grep` and `ls` together . I found the `bash` equivalent questions for it on SO here [List files with certain extensions with ls and grep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1447625/list-files-with-certain-extensions-with-ls-and-grep) but no R equivalent. I did refer these two related questions but they are quite different :

[Return elements of list as independent objects in global environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13795526/return-elements-of-r-list-as-independent-objects-in-global-environment) , [How can I make a list of all dataframes that are in my global environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25509879/how-can-i-make-a-list-of-all-dataframes-that-are-in-my-global-environment)

Comment: @vagabond You can extract the `local` and `national` and split on those

Comment: But you showed two patterns.  So what I thought was you need all datasets with a particular pattern in one list and another in different list or a sort of nested list.

Comment: Could you post the error as well.

Comment: `Error in mget(grep(pattern = "q.*local", as.character(ls()))) : 
  invalid first argument` . Sorry I didn't mention that clearly in the question - I wanted to make two lists - one for each pattern.

Comment: After creating some datasets, I was able to do this comfortably using `mget(ls(pattern="q\\d+local"))`, but why do you need `grep` (not tested yet)

Comment: yes, u r right . . I don't need the `grep` at all ! please post as an answer.

Comment: With object names like that I would suggest you *begin* the session by putting them into a list

Comment: @vagabond As mentioned by Richard Scriven, I would also have read it like `lst <- lapply(list.files(pattern='^q\\d+'), function(x) read.table(x, header=TRUE))`  Please change the pattern accordingly.

Comment: yes, but i wanted to individually clean each data frame before putting them all into a list. Each of them has specific problems and I am not very hands on with adding, removing columns, merging with other data frames while keeping everything in a list. I know it is the right way to go but I'm not there yet !

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I have used the following, obviously this will need to be repeated for each pattern.

```
Pattern1<-grep("local",names(.GlobalEnv),value=TRUE)
     Pattern1_list<-do.call("list",mget(Pattern1))
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a shorter solution inspired in the one from W.Kessler:

```
Pattern1_list <- list(mget(ls(pattern = "local")))[[1]]
```