# Remove columns with certain column name patterns in multiple dataframes in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have >100 dataframes loaded into R. I want to remove all the columns from all data frames containing a certain pattern, in the example case below "abc".

```
df1 <- data.frame(`abc_1` = rep(3, 5), `b` = seq(1, 5, 1), `c` = letters[1:5])
df2 <- data.frame(`d` = rep(5, 5), `e_abc` = seq(2, 6, 1), `f` = letters[6:10])
df3 <- data.frame(`g` = rep(5, 5), `h` = seq(2, 6, 1), `i_a_abc` = letters[6:10])
```

I would thus like to remove the column abc_1 in df1, e_abc in df2 and i_a_abc in df3. How could this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do all of your dataframes start with or contain a shared string (e.g., `df`)? If yes, then it might be easier to put all your dataframes in a list by [using that shared string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26738302/make-list-of-objects-in-global-environment-matching-certain-string-pattern) and then apply the function to remove the `abc` columns in every dataframe in that list.

You can then read your dataframes back into your environment with `list2env()`, but it probably is in your interest to keep everything in a list for convenience.

```
library(dplyr)
df1 <- data.frame(`abc_1` = rep(3, 5), `b` = seq(1, 5, 1), `c` = letters[1:5])
df2 <- data.frame(`d` = rep(5, 5), `e_abc` = seq(2, 6, 1), `f` = letters[6:10])
df3 <- data.frame(`g` = rep(5, 5), `h` = seq(2, 6, 1), `i_a_abc` = letters[6:10])

dfpattern <- grep("df", names(.GlobalEnv), value = TRUE)
dflist <- do.call("list", mget(dfpattern))

dflist <- lapply(dflist, function(x){ x <- x %>% select(!contains("abc")) })
list2env(dflist, envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

Comment: This is a very good suggestion, however I realize my example was not the best since all dataframs does not contain a shared string.

Comment: `mget(ls(pattern = 'df'))` should get the dfs in a list

Comment: @PontusHedberg, are the only objects loaded into your environment right now the 100+ dataframes? Also, have you looked into the option of reading all your dataframes as a list directly into R (i.e., not loading them in as dataframes at all)? That way you can bypass the hard part and just use the code starting with `lapply`.

Comment: That is actually a great idea. I tried to find how to read multiple excel-files into a list directly, but could not find an answer. Anything you know how to do?

Comment: [Have you looked here?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11433532/14992857) This does assume that all your files are in the same folder/location. Instead of `.csv`, use `.xlsx` (or whatever is appropriate) and instead of `read.delim`, try [`read_excel`](https://readxl.tidyverse.org/reference/read_excel.html) or [`read.xlsx`](https://ycphs.github.io/openxlsx/reference/read.xlsx.html).